# iSCSI connection is gone and when reconnected drive can't be accessed anymore on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iscsi

My client has QNAP library that I've used to share 2 iSCSI connections. One to physical machine and the other to virtual machine on top of that machine. One is 4TB (connected to physical machine) and the other one is 1.4TB. Both use Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

It's 2nd time that iSCSI drive disappeared from virtual machine (and physical host still is connected to the other iSCSI device) and when I used iSCSI initiator to reconnect the drives, they were reconnected but the 1.4TB is treated as RAW and I can't access data. The first time we assumed it was accident but now it's clearly something wrong.

What can be happening and why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Open a command window on the VM and do a ping -t to the qnap, then when you lose the iscsi connection see if you also lost pings. I'm no fan of iscsi personally but the one thing we know is that is uses the same 'works' as everything else, so if you're losing a connection we can diagnose it the same ways.

Comment: It happens once per month or so .. It's not very common I don't even remember date it happend last time just that it happend. Right now I'm trying to recover some data but I'm preety sure all is there just partition table is gone or so.

Comment: What's your iSCSI server?  We've got a Windows iSCSI server and the monthly automatic reboots that Microsoft was forcing was breaking our iSCSI (connections get dropped and won't come back up automatically, have to shutdown client servers and manually restart services).